# Flutter, how can I write desired function with dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to print an error message if a letter comes after the first two letters in the following expression.

EN**545454545**

Comment: can you provide more examples?

Comment: this bank Iban adress

Comment: why don't you use a package for this instead creating yourself? https://pub.dev/packages/iban

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `tryParse` method of `num`, if it fails parsing it returns `null` which means it contained some illegal characters

```dart
  String code = 'EN545454545';
  if (num.tryParse(code.substring(2)) == null) {
    // Handle error
  }
```

Comment: [https://i.imgur.com/CDOGyPC.png]

Comment: I had a missing parenthesis, and the method is `substring` not `subString`. I have editted my answer.

Comment: substring(2, 3) is index number 2 and 3 here? So how do I get all remaining indexes

Comment: The start index is inclusive (2), and the end index (3) is exclusive. So basically at index 2 which is '5'

Comment: OK, but there is a logical error. If all letters up to the specified index are letters, it gives an error output. For example, if there is even 1 letter 20 characters long, I want it to give an error.

Comment: This is bank IBAN adress, i want to for this

Comment: I have editted my answer. You try to parse the whole code after the first two letters to a `num`, if it fails then it contains illegal characters. However you may also need to check if the first two characters are actually letters.

Comment: This answer format never the criteria as I believe scientific notation can be parsed.